# Linux: No output from a program in a .sh script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to execute a Windows program in Linux, and I want to get the output (stdout) from that process. I put this text into a .sh file:
`wine Blockland.exe ptlaaxobimwroe -dedicated -port 30000 >> consoleLog.txt`
It executed the program, but created a blank file. This command always works when directly executed in a Terminal window. So why isn't it printing the output to the file when in a .sh script?

Comment: Show us the rest of your shell script, as well as the how you execute it.

Answer (score 1):

It could be sending output to stderr. To account for this possibility, try

```
wine Blockland.exe ptlaaxobimwroe -dedicated -port 30000 2>&1 >>consoleLog.txt
```

The `2>&1` bit redirects stderr (file descriptor 2) to stdout (file descriptor 1). Then it redirects stdout (which includes stderr output now) to your log file.

Comment: It always correctly writes the output to the file when typed into Terminal. Why doesn't it work in a shell script?